# Detecting _which_ finger touches the screen on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, gestures

I tried searching this in even broader terms, but couldn't come up with anything and I am already guessing it's *not even possible*. Is there a way to detect which one (thumb, index, middle, ring or pinky) of the five fingers touches the screen?

Comment: Your guess is correct: you cannot even tell that it is a finger (as opposed to, say, a toe, an elbow, or a stylus) touching the screen, let alone the exact finger.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Not possible till date.
 Check this:- [Event Handling Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)